# jquery deferred with async calls

Tags: ajax, jquery-deferred

Please find the below code snippet:

HTML:

```
<div>
<span> First Name : <input type="text" id="firstName" name="First Name"/></span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
<span>Student Id: <input type="text" id="studentId" name="studentId"/></span>
<span>Teacher Id: <input type="text" id="teacherId" name="teacherId"/></span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
<span>Student Name : <input type="text" id="stdLastName" name="stdLastName"/></span>
<span>Student Age :<input type="text" id="stdAge" name="stdAge"/></span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
<span>Teacher Name : <input type="text" id="tchrLastName" name="tchrLastName"/></span>
<span>Teacher Age : <input type="text" id="tchrAge" name="tchrAge"/></span>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#firstName').focus();

var d1= new $.Deferred();

$('#firstName').blur(populatePage());

//called on blur of first name 
function populatePage() {
    $.when(populateStdDetails(),populateTchrDetails()).done(function(resp1, resp2){
          $('#stdLastName').val(resp1[0].stdName);
        $('#stdAge').val(resp1[0].age);
        $('#tchrLastName').val(resp2[0].stdName);
        $('#tchrAge').val(resp2[0].age);
            console.log('All details populated....');
        d1.resolve();

  });
  return d1;
}  

//first ajax call
function populateStdDetails() {
    if($('#firstName').val() != '' && $('#studentId').val() !='') {
        return $.ajax({
        url : '/someURL?studentId='+studentId+'&firstName='+firstName,
      type :'GET',
      contentType:'json'
    });
    }
}

//second ajax call
function populateTchrDetails() {
    if($('#firstName').val() != '' && $('#teacherId').val() !='') {
        return $.ajax({
        url : '/someURL?teacherId='+teacherId+'&firstName='+firstName,
      type :'GET',
      contentType:'json'
    });
    }
}

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    //wait for the ajax calls to be completed
  $.when(populatePage()).done(function(e){
    console.log('All done !!!!');
    //Move to next page;
  });
});
```

The First Name text field has an onblur event attached which works fine in usual scenario but when the focus is on "First Name" and "Submit" is clicked, the submit function is called instead of waiting for the onblur event to be completed.

Comment: Note that in real code, ajax requests in jQuery already return their own promise so you do NOT need to wrap them in yet another promise.  If you show us your real code, we could actually share how to best use promises with the real code.  Theoretical questions with make believe code are rarely as valuable references as real code where contributors can show you all the things you could do better.

Comment: @jfriend00: Please find the fiddle where I have depicted the actual requirement : https://jsfiddle.net/diptesh2007/ebz6ey1m/

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with that code.  For starters, it's full of the [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).  If you put that code into your question per the posting guidelines here, we can show you lots better ways to do what you're doing.  As I suspected, you don't need to be creating new promises at all because you already have promises from the `$.ajax()` calls that can just be used directly.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that resolving promises from an ajax is not required as it can be used directly, but actually we have build a wrapper over ajax which allows the caller to implement callback only. Any way I have updated the original question with the more actual code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed deferred.resolve in wrong places in your timeout functions. Do it like this way:

```
function doSomething(deffered) {
    $('#log').append('doSomething');
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred;
};

function ajaxRequests1(deferred) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#log').append('......ajaxRequests1');
        deferred.resolve(); 
    }, 1000);
    return deferred;
};

function ajaxRequests2(deferred) {
   setTimeout(function(){
        $('#log').append('.....ajaxRequests2');
        deferred.resolve();
   }, 5000); 
   return deferred;
};

var func1 = function () {
        var promise = new $.Deferred();
        ajaxRequests1(promise);
        return promise;
    }

var func2 = function () {
        var promise = new $.Deferred();
        ajaxRequests2(promise);
        return promise;
}

var stepFinal = function() {
       var promise = new $.Deferred();
       doSomething(promise);
       return promise;
}

$.when(func1().promise(), func2().promise())
    .done(function () {
            stepFinal().done();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you want `populatePage()` to be called when focus leaves #firstname, and if the user also clicked on the submit button and you want the submit operation to wait for that blur action to finish, you can do this:

```
$('#firstName').blur(function(e) {
    // call populatePage and set the resulting promise as a data item so
    // the submit handler can get access to it
    var self = $(this);
    var p = populatePage();
    self.data("blurPromise", p);

    // when this promise is done, clear the blurPromise
    p.always(function() {
        self.removeData("blurPromise");
    });
});

//called on blur of first name 
function populatePage() {
    return $.when(populateStdDetails(),populateTchrDetails()).done(function(resp1, resp2){
        $('#stdLastName').val(resp1[0].stdName);
        $('#stdAge').val(resp1[0].age);
        $('#tchrLastName').val(resp2[0].stdName);
        $('#tchrAge').val(resp2[0].age);
        console.log('All details populated....');
    });
}  

//first ajax call
function populateStdDetails() {
    if($('#firstName').val() != '' && $('#studentId').val() !='') {
        return $.ajax({
            url : '/someURL?studentId='+studentId+'&firstName='+firstName,
            type :'GET',
            contentType:'json'
        });
    } else {
        // just return already resolved promise
        return $.when();
    }
}

//second ajax call
function populateTchrDetails() {
    if($('#firstName').val() != '' && $('#teacherId').val() !='') {
        return $.ajax({
            url : '/someURL?teacherId='+teacherId+'&firstName='+firstName,
            type :'GET',
            contentType:'json'
        });
    } else {
        return $.when();
    }
}

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    // get blur promise or dummy resolved promise
    var p = $("#firstName").data("blurPromise") || $.when();
    p.then(function() {
        // do your submit logic here
        // The onBlur handler is done now
    });
});
```

Things I've updated in your promise handling code:

1. Use the `$.ajax()` promises directly without wrapping them in yet another promise.
2. Use the `$.when()` promises directly without wrapping them in yet another promise.
3. When using an `if` statement to decide whether or not to execute an asynchronous operation, it is usually best to also return a promise in the `else` arm so your function consistently always returns a promise.  If there's nothing else to do in the `else` clause, then a shortcut for returning an already resolved promise in jQuery is to just `return $.when();`.
4. Be warned that `.done()` is jQuery-specific and not standard promise behavior.  If you're already on jQuery 3.x or higher, then you should probably switch to `.then()` and then your promises will behave like the promise standard.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since the first text field has an onblur event attached, consider what happens when the focus is on field "First Name" and "Submit" is clicked. The onblur event is called and as well as the "Submit" function will be called. I want the onblur function to be completed before the submit function is executed. DO you think the e.preventDefault() can prevent the blur event?

Comment: @diptesh2007 - I'm trying to understand all the uses cases here.  If the focus is on First Name and the user clicks the submit button, do you want to call `populatePage()` just once and then submit the form when that is done?  If the user is on some other field, do you also want to call `populatePage()` once before submit and then submit the form when that's done?  So, are you just trying to get `populatePage()` called when losing focus or when submitting?  Also, is there an actual `<form>`?  Your HTML doesn't show those tags.

Comment: I want the populatePage() to be called only during onblur of "First Name" field, which is happening currently. During submit, I just want the submit function to be called irrespective of which field has focus,but currently populate Page() is getting called if the "First Name" has focus and Submit is clicked. In our case the form is submitted through ajax,not through the default form action.

Comment: @diptesh2007 - OK, I totally modified my answer to do what I think you're asking for.

Comment: @diptesh2007 - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.